# chown: invalid user: ‘+x’

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, chown

some_file.py:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
print("Hello World!")
```

On terminal:

```
sudo chown +x some_file.py
chown: invalid user: ‘+x’
```

I want to make the file executable.

Comment: `chmod --help`?

Comment: Try looking at the man page for chown `man chown`

Comment: It happens, just remember `chown` -- **ch**ange **own**er, and `chmod` is **ch**ange **mod**e.

Comment: Sorry guys, my bad, thanks for your time alecxs, matt-freake and david-c-rankin.

Answer (score 7):

The `chown` command stands for *change ownership*. That's why you get *invalid user: ‘+x’*, because it was expecting a user as input.

If you want to change permissions of a file you must use the `chmod` command. To make a file executable for the *user owner* of that file you could try

```
chmod u+x some_file.py
```

Comment: Sorry my bad, thank  you for your time.